# How to send a sms message Via ADSL Router / Modem

Tags: adsl

I just want to know that how to send a sms via ADSL modem / Router ?? Just searched the internet and asked some friends.but couldn't get an answer.....!! Please help

Answer (score 1):

This is something that is not possible as you need to be able to talk to the cellular network. Your ADSL modem does not have any means to communicate with such networks.

You best bet is to use a SMS gateway such as [clickatell](http://www.clickatell.com/). There are loads of similiar services, so you will need to do some research.

Another option is to buy a GSM gateway and hook it up to your server. [Hybertone](http://www.hybertone.com/en/) and various companies sell these. The problem is that you will need to subscribe to a cellular provider for a sim card to send text messages. Interfacing is also a lot more complicated as you will need a way to talk to the device.

In my opinion, your best bet is to sign up with a SMS gateway as the rates charged would be cheaper and the transmissions more reliable. The implementation would also be much more simplier as they would provide an API or some sort of a webservice.

Answer (score 0):

Some networks will allow you to use email to SMS, but it depends on the country and the network. An example of this is [here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/939/sms_email_cingular_nextel_sprint_tmobile_verizon_virgin/)